# serialization of object to json in rest-assured request body

Tags: java, json, resteasy, rest-assured

I'm making a rest api using [resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/), and testing it with [rest-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/).

Let's say that I have a class, `message`, with a property `text`.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class message {
  @XmlElement
  public String text;
}
```

The following test will try to post this object to a given url:

```
message msg = new message();
msg.text = "some message";

expect()
  .statusCode(200)
.given()
   .contentType("application/json")
   .body(msg)
.when()
  .post("/message");
```

The msg object is serialized to json and posted, but not in the way that I want - not in the way resteasy need, that is.

What's posted:

```
{ "text": "some message" }
```

What's working:

```
{ "message": { "text": "some message" } }
```

Does anyone have any clue on how I can make this work as expected?

Comment: I have 2 questions for you:
How did you know what was posted? And 
How did you apply the solution you marked as an answer?
Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I no longer have the code available to me. But if I remember right, it comes down to what packages you make available. In our case we used maven. Finding what was posted shouldn't be that hard. Use a proxy or a log or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the built in Jettison JSON serializer with RestEasy. Jettison uses the XML-> Json convention (also known as BadgerFish). Replace Jettison with Jackson or GSon to get a JSon format compatible with RestAssured.

Answer (score 6):

I know there's already an answer for this but i want to share the way i was able to send a json object. Someone may find it helpful

```
// import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
person.put("firstname", "Jonathan");
person.put("lastname", "Morales");

JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
address.put("City", "Bogotá");
address.put("Street", "Some street");
person.put("address", address);

String jsonString = person.toJSONString();
// {"address":{"Street":"Some street","City":"Bogotá"},"lastname":"Morales","firstname":"Jonathan"}

// import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
given().contentType("application/json")
       .body(jsonString)
       .expect().statusCode(200)
       .when().post("http://your-rest-service/");
```

Comment: Still have few doubts , I created Java hashmap and it failed. But your solution worked , any idea why it might have failed with hashamp approach . I have nested json as per your example.

Comment: Hey vikramvi, I did this long time ago and I can't really tell what happens when using a hashmap.